# Past time while testing with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm just curious on some good practices around testing for time in Rspec, ie. the datetime data type and the date data type. ON the shorthand, this is the problem i currently have, i'm trying to test the lsting page ie. index.html.erb but am looking for a past tense time method to use not future tense time method.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'List Objects' do 
    it 'shows all objects' do 

        object11 = Object.create(
            title: 'Local Stuff',
            description: 'An article on local disputes',
            posted_from: 'New Jersey',
            posted_by: 'Ned Flanders',
            posted_at: 6.days.from_now <-- Looking for a past tense time method to use.
            )


        visit objects_url


        expect(page).to have_text(object1.title)
        expect(page).to have_text(object1.description)
        expect(page).to have_text(object1.posted_from) 
        expect(page).to have_text(object1.posted_by)
        expect(page).to have_text(object1.posted_from)
        expect(page).to have_text(object1.posted_at)
```

Comment: Very unclear to me what you're trying to test.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i've updated the question, its a listing/index.html page just checking if everything is there where it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`#ago`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M000985) method:

```
    object11 = Object.create(
        title: 'Local Stuff',
        description: 'An article on local disputes',
        posted_from: 'New Jersey',
        posted_by: 'Ned Flanders',
        posted_at: 6.days.ago
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Uri, Is this for the date type or datetime, or both.

Comment: @SpencerHire this method returns `Time`, but it should be converted to the required type automatically, so it should fit both (just like `#from_now`